How to Load and Parse a Large PDF from Stream Chunk by Chunk Without Loading It Completely into Memory?
I'm currently working on a project that involves loading and parsing a large PDF file (over 2GB) from a stream without loading the entire file into memory. I have created a ReadStream from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) / S3 and want to efficiently read the PDF in chunks, extracting text and other relevant information for further processing.
What I tried
I tried various PDF-parsing libraries like pdf-lib, pdf-parse, and pdf2json, but they don't seem to support parsing using streams. They first completely load the PDF into memory and then parse it.
What I expected
I was hoping to find a library or method that allows me to process a large PDF file without exhausting memory resources.
Additionally, I would like to know how this approach can be extended to handle other document types, such as CSV, DOCX, or Excel files.
If anyone has experience with handling large PDFs or other document types in this manner or can share best practices for stream processing, I would greatly appreciate your insights!

Normal PDFs needn't be organized in a way that supports unbuffered streaming. Resources and contents of each page can wildly be spread over the whole document. Also the cross reference table (and often the alternative cross reference stream, too) is at the end of the PDF. Thus, to properly start parsing a PDF one has to start at its end. The exception here are the so called "linearized PDFs" (aka "PDFs with Fast Web View"). But there is no wide requirement to create linearized PDFs.

Thank you for your reply! It sounds like linearized PDFs would be ideal here, but since I don’t have control over the format of incoming files, I can’t guarantee they’ll be set up that way.
